# Printing CPU number similar to ftrace

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, ftrace

I want to print CPU number on which the current process or function is executing similar to ftrace like this:

```
 TASK-PID   CPU#      TIMESTAMP  FUNCTION
    | |       |          |         |
<idle>-0     [002]  23636.756054: ttwu_do_activate.constprop.89 <-try_to_wake_up
<idle>-0     [002]  23636.756054: activate_task <-ttwu_do_activate.constprop.89
<idle>-0     [002]  23636.756055: enqueue_task <-activate_task
```

How do I get that value? I suppose its there in some function of `start_kernel` function. Can we print its value? I am using `linux-4.1` kernel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For printing current cpu in kernel, the [cpu](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/sched.h#L1493) field of `task_struct` can be used. Note that the kernel configuration `CONFIG_THREAD_INFO_IN_TASK` should be enabled. This will work for 4.9 kernel.

```
printk("My current cpu is %d\n", current->cpu);
```

`smp_processor_id()` also can be used if cpu field is not available.

Comment: I want to print CPU number very early during kernel initialization , so I have tried to use `smp_processor_id()` after `boot_cpu_init()` function where processor gets activated.But I get some garbage symbol and kernel hangs. Architecture is `armv7`. I tried like `char str = smp_processor_id() + '0';`. Then `printch(str);` I am using printch to enable early printing.

Comment: At very early would it be different to 0?

Comment: ``pr_info("Booting Linux on physical CPU 0x%lx\n", (unsigned long)mpidr);`` in ``smp_setup_processor_id()`` should help on arm for boot cpu. Do you see this message?